# iTextSharp LGPLv2.Core fails to show arabic in rtl when converting from html to pdf

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, itext, c#-3.0

Im using [iTextSharp LGPLv2.Core](https://github.com/VahidN/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core) to convert html to pdf with arabic content.

When pdf converted, arabic text shown LTR instead of RTL and separated characters as shown below

[image]

I'v registered three types of fonts none of them worked:

- Tahoma: showing LTR and separated.
- Arabtype: showing LTR and separated.
- arialuni: not showing Arabic characters at all.

Here is a code snippet of what i did:

```
try
        {
            var paymentReceipt = await _appointmentAppService.GetPaymentReceiptAsync(checkOutId);
            string invoiceHtml = RenderView("PaymentReceipt", paymentReceipt);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                var styleSheet = new StyleSheet();

                styleSheet.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, "encoding", "Identity-H");
                styleSheet.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FONT, "arabic");

                string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                string fontPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "fonts", "ARABTYPE.TTF");

                FontFactory.Register(fontPath, "arabic");
                //FontFactory.Register(TestUtils.GetTahomaFontPath());
                //FontFactory.Register(TestUtils.GetArialUnicodeMSFontPath());

                var unicodeFontProvider = FontFactoryImp.Instance;
                unicodeFontProvider.DefaultEmbedding = BaseFont.EMBEDDED;
                unicodeFontProvider.DefaultEncoding = BaseFont.IDENTITY_H;

                var props = new Hashtable
                {
                    { "font_factory", unicodeFontProvider }
                };

                var document = new Document();
                var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

                document.AddAuthor(TestUtils.Author);
                document.Open();

                var objects = HtmlWorker.ParseToList(
                    new StringReader(invoiceHtml),
                    styleSheet,
                    props
                );

                foreach (IElement element in objects)
                {
                    document.Add(element);
                }

                document.Close();
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `itext7` but the version you are using, is most likely iText .NET (formerly known as iTextSharp) version 4.0.x or 4.1.x. That's a really old version. Have you tried with iText 7? Also, for complex writing systems that have ligatures (compound characters) such as Arabic, you need the pdfCalligraph add-on. I'm sorry but it really won't work in the old version you are using. Here's a link to the product page, have a look at the video too. https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph

Comment: If you look at the video, you'll see that your problem is exactly as described in example 2 (at 2:18 into the video). You already have a font, but no RTL nor ligatures. pdfCalligraph solves that. You should know that it only exists as a commercial product.